# Steam OpenID auth in Swift: only passes every other attempt

Tags: swift, authentication, openid, steam

**Solution:**

As a user below stated, I had to escape/encode the `+` (`%2B`) symbol in the nonce and sig URL elements. First I edited both elements as the URLComponent object. In that case, the following conversion to a URL object would replace the `%` in the sig by itself again, making it `%252B`.

I resolved that problem by converting the URL to a plain string, editing that and converting it back to a URL, rather than editing the URLComponent elements.

---

I'm working on an app with Swift to accompany a project I'm on. We want to handle the login process via Steam OpenID. On the website (built with Angular) it works flawlessly, but I'm having some troubles on the app part.

**This is my problem:**

Our backend doesn't provide me a token on every attempt.

It seems to be rather random when it passes and when it fails, but in total it's been about every other attempt.

I suspected the OpenID library in our backend to be the fault, so I did multiple tries on Steam's endpoint by myself, but the behavior is exactly the same.

**This is my code:**

This is called on login button tap:

```
var session: ASWebAuthenticationSession?

func signIn() {
    
    let scheme = "myauth"
    
    let authUrl = URL(string: "https://steamcommunity.com/openid/login
        ?openid.ns=http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0
        &openid.claimed_id=http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/identifier_select
        &openid.identity=http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/identifier_select
        &openid.return_to=https://mywebsite.com/appauth
        &openid.realm=https://mywebsite.com
        &openid.mode=checkid_setup")!
    
    self.session = ASWebAuthenticationSession.init(url: authUrl, callbackURLScheme: scheme, completionHandler: { callbackURL, error in
        guard error == nil, let successURL = callbackURL else {
            print("Error: ASWebAuthSession returned with: \(error!)")
            return
        }
        var queryItems = URLComponents(string: successURL.absoluteString)!.queryItems!
        
        HttpService.getSteamResponse(queryItems: queryItems)
    })
    
    session?.presentationContextProvider = self
    session?.prefersEphemeralWebBrowserSession = true
    self.session?.start()
}
```

This is the referenced function:

```
static func getSteamResponse(queryItems: [URLQueryItem]) {
    
    var mutatedItems = queryItems
    if var item = queryItems.enumerated().first(where: {$0.element.name == "openid.mode"}) {
        item.element.value = "check_authentication"
        mutatedItems[item.offset] = item.element
    } else {
       print("Error: Steam check has no item 'openid.mode'")
    }
    
    var urlComps = URLComponents(string: "https://steamcommunity.com/openid/login")!
    urlComps.queryItems = mutatedItems
    let url = urlComps.url!
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
        
        guard let data = data else {
            debugPrint("Error: Steam check responded with: \(String(describing: error))")
            return
        }
        
        if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse{
            print("Info: Steam check responsed with: \(httpResponse.statusCode)")
        }
        
        print("Info: Steam check data: \(String(decoding: data, as: UTF8.self))")
    }.resume()
}
```

This includes some additional check that might not be necessary and it might not be very optimized at some points (I'm still learning Swift), but all in all it should be working (and does... sometimes)

**Further information:**

Note that I replaced the actual links to our project with placeholders.

As I understand it, the ASWebAuthenticationSession callback does only need an URL scheme, which I replaced with `myauth`. Since I noticed Steam (or OpenID in general?) not liking custom URL schemes, I instead use `https://mywebsite.com/appauth`, which redirects with 301 to something like `myauth://foobar.com` with all parameters, so I can receive them in the app (I guess this would work via Universal links as well, but I don't have a paid dev account yet).

Now when I run this code, I can't get a consistent response. It's always a `200` with `ns:http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0` and seemingly random `is_valid:false` or `is_valid:true`.

I ran this multiple times, tried redeploying the app in-between and even erasing the simulator device, but I can't get consistent results.

Unfortunately I can only try so many times, because Steam will block the login from my network after about 15 logins.

On my last trial I received `false, false, true, false, true`.

My guess would be there to be some issues with concurrency that I can't notice.

I appreciate any help on this topic!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encountered the same thing in Golang. Turned out, I didn't escape the nonce and sig string, and it was modified in GET parameter in the request

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I'm answering pretty late, since I didn't find the motivation to continue on the project yet. Would you mind elaborating a little further? I think your referencing escaping characters. Even though there are some special characters in the nonce (like +, /, =,...), I believe they don't have any special encoding, since Swift outputs them in plain text (as should be). Are you maybe referencing the keyword @escaping, so that the async behaviour is the problem here? Unfortunately I'm also not into Golang, so I don't get any reference from that.

Comment: What also amazes me is how random my results are. There's like not even a scheme of how often is occurs, like exactly every second time due to some caching or whatever. But instead it sometimes works thrice in a row and then thrice not anymore. Seemingly random, but on average every other time.

Comment: There is a chance to have a symbol "+" in the key sent by Valve. In my case, escaping this symbol was a problem. Every time there was "+" in the key, the authorization failed, until I url-escaped it